# How do I authenticate as super user in a Google Compute Engine instance to install Chrome Remote Desktop?

Tags: google-chrome, google-compute-engine, chrome-remote-desktop

I would like to Chrome Remote Desktop to my GCE instance. Normally, sudo does not ask me for a password on this instance. However, when trying to enable Chrome Remote Desktop, I get a GUI popup that asks for a password and won't take no for an answer. What should I do here?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpk81.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that's not your local user account that's asking for the pasword?